# Select all data with no duplicate data

Tags: sql

I have some data in database:

> **Name | Country | Status**
>
> Mary  | USA | Pending
>
> Jane| Japan | Pending
>
> Jane | Korea | Pending
>
> Adrian | China | Pending
>
> Peter | Singapore | Pending
>
> Jack | Malaysia | Pending
>
> Adrian | China | Updated
>
> Jane | Japan | Updated

May I know how to use the SELECT query to select all the data with no duplicate data? (If the duplicates data exist, select only the Status with Updated)

Comment: It depends on what fields you consider : ex. should `status` be taken in account or not ?

Comment: ^ had this same thought

Comment: All the fields i also need to consider. For the above example, i want to select Mary, Jane (from Korea), Peter, Jack, Adrian (from status updated) and Jane (from status updated)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT Name, Country, MAX(Status) as Status FROM (
SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT *
FROM NameCountry
ORDER BY Name ASC, Country ASC, Status DESC
) G
GROUP BY G.Name, G.Country
ORDER BY G.Name, G.Country
```

Check my [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e3e63/1)

Comment: Thanks. May i know why must use "TOP 100 PERCENT*"? Sorry because i am new in sql.

Comment: @Ian If you have an inner query or sub query and you are using ORDER BY you need to use a TOP clause otherwise it will not work. And make it 100% so that it will show everything.

Answer (score 0):

From your comment, you seem to mean only data where the first two columns are duplicated.  The easiest way, I think, is to use `row_number()`, which is available in most databases:

```
select name, country, status
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by name, country
                                order by (case when status = 'Pending' then 0 else 1 end)
                               ) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1
```